# How to get the value from other variable for another setter in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I am building a simple CMS using Symfony.  Now, I have a working CRUD for Page Entity. Now, I want to add another column/field for url.  The url field will not be displayed in the public form.  What I want to do is get the value from the Title field, replace all the spaces with hyphens and there is my url.  But I am having an issue implementing this one, url comes as null.  Here is what I've done so far.

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=10)
 */
private $url;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $title;



/**
 * Set url
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return Page
 */
public function setUrl($title)
{
    $lstr = strtolower($title);

    $this->url = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $lstr);

    return $this;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You're returning the object (`return $this;`) and not returning the url. Change it to `return $this->url;`.

Comment: I still get this error
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Page (url, display, title, content, date, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "2015-05-22 02:16:13", "asdf"]:

Comment: Is `$title` empty by any chance?

Comment: no, it is not.  I filled in all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Set url
 *
 * @prePersist
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return Page
 */
public function setUrl()
{
    $lstr = strtolower($this->title);

    $this->url = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $lstr);

    return $this;
}
```

@prePersist annotation will execute this method before persisting to database, so you will get what you want! I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @Motammen but I still get this error:
>An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Page (url, display, title, content, date, author) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "asdf", "asdf", "asdf", "2015-05-22 02:16:13", "asdf"]: 
which means that setUrl() is not getting the $title value.  but as you can see, the title isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your url column to nullable. Keep your setter as default like

```
public function setUrl($url)
{
    $this->url = $url;
    return $this;
}
```

But change your getter into:

```
public function getUrl()
{
    if(null !== $this->url){
        return $this->url;
    }

    $lstr = strtolower($this->title);

    return preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $lstr);
}
```